# vscode: how to autoindent jupyter notebook ipynb file?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, visual-studio-code

Is it possible to enable auto indent in vscode for ipynb files please?

[image]

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/jupyter-support

Comment: I have the same problem.

Comment: I never imagined you could open .ipynb files on VSC... following!

Comment: It should just work. Otherwise file a bug at https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python.

Comment: By the way, this problem appeared a few days ago, before that everything worked, reinstallation does not help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that version 1.47.0 has corrected the bug. And now the auto-indent works in Jupyter again.